# How to set the run name of a PipelineJob

Tags: python, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I have this code to start a VertexAI pipeline job:

```
import google.cloud.aiplatform as vertexai

vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID,staging_bucket=PIPELINE_ROOT)

job = vertexai.PipelineJob(
    display_name='pipeline-test-1',
    template_path='xgb_pipe.json'
)

job.run()
```

which works nicely, but the `run name` label is a random number.  How can I specify the `run name`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value shown in "Run Name" by defining `name` when defining the pipeline.

```
@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name="automl-image-training-v2")
```

When defining the `name` using `@kfp.dsl.pipeline`, it will automatically append the date and time when the pipeline is ran. Proceed with compiling and running the pipeline to see the change in "Run Name".

[image]

I used the code in [Vertex AI pipeline examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/pipelines/google_cloud_pipeline_components_automl_images.ipynb). See pipeline code:

```
@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name="automl-image-training-v2")
def pipeline(project: str = PROJECT_ID, region: str = REGION):
    ds_op = gcc_aip.ImageDatasetCreateOp(
        project=project,
        display_name="flowers",
        gcs_source="gs://cloud-samples-data/vision/automl_classification/flowers/all_data_v2.csv",
        import_schema_uri=aip.schema.dataset.ioformat.image.single_label_classification,
    )

    training_job_run_op = gcc_aip.AutoMLImageTrainingJobRunOp(
        project=project,
        display_name="train-automl-flowers",
        prediction_type="classification",
        model_type="CLOUD",
        base_model=None,
        dataset=ds_op.outputs["dataset"],
        model_display_name="train-automl-flowers",
        training_fraction_split=0.6,
        validation_fraction_split=0.2,
        test_fraction_split=0.2,
        budget_milli_node_hours=8000,
    )

    endpoint_op = gcc_aip.EndpointCreateOp(
        project=project,
        location=region,
        display_name="train-automl-flowers",
    )

    gcc_aip.ModelDeployOp(
        model=training_job_run_op.outputs["model"],
        endpoint=endpoint_op.outputs["endpoint"],
        automatic_resources_min_replica_count=1,
        automatic_resources_max_replica_count=1,
    )
```